squirrel postgresql error syntax error at or near ","
I'm working on a backend service to add a user to a Postgres database using squirrel and echo packages. I have the following the code below but I keep getting an postgres error pq: syntax error at or near ",", when I do a POST request with the following JSON:
{
  "user_name": "IronMan",
  "first_name": "Tony",
  "last_name": "Stark",
  "email": "ironman@marvel.com",
  "user_status": "I",
  "department": "Comics"
 }

Note: in the database table, a user_id is automatically generated.
Here is my code:
func CreateUser(c echo.Context) error {
    newUser := new(models.User)
    c.Bind(&newUser)

    //dbTableName := os.Getenv("DB_TABLE_NAME")

    sqlStatement, _, err := sq.Insert(dbTableName).
        Columns("user_name", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "user_status", "department").
        Values(newUser.User_Name, newUser.First_Name, newUser.Last_Name, newUser.Email,
            newUser.User_Status, newUser.Department).
        ToSql()
    if err != nil {
        c.Logger().Panicf("Unable to create query: %s \n%s", sqlStatement, err)
    }

    row := db.DB.QueryRow(sqlStatement)
    err = row.Scan(newUser.USER_ID, newUser.User_Name, newUser.First_Name, newUser.Last_Name,
        newUser.Email, newUser.User_Status, newUser.Department)
    if err != nil {
        c.Logger().Panicf("Unable to scan results query:\n%s\n%s", err, row)
    }
    //defer sqlStatement.Close()

    return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, newUser)
}

The error appears to coming from the Scan function in squirrel, but I don't understand if the error is saying I am missing a column, because I have them all listed.

If you print your sqlStatement variable, you'll see that it is a parameterized statement, which should be prepared. As the docs of ToSql()(string, []interface{}, error say, "ToSql returns a SQL representation of the Sqlizer, along with a slice of args as passed to e.g. database/sql.Exec".
So what you should do, is something along these lines:
sqlStmt, sqlParams, err := sq.Insert("foo").Columns("bar").Values("baz").ToSql()

// sqlStmt is now INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ($1)
// sqlParams is now []interface{{"baz"}}
db.QueryRow(sqlStmt, sqlParams...).Scan()

I suggest taking a look at insert_test.go to see what other options you have.

original sqlStatement comes out as:
INSERT INTO users (user_name,first_name,last_name,email,user_status,department) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)

I think I am misinterpreting, are you for the Values function I need to insert params like
Values("$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6", params).ToSql() where params is a slice like:
params := []string{
newUser.User_Name,
newUser.First_Name,
newUser.Last_Name,
newUser.Email,
newUser.User_Status,
newUser.Department,
}
